# Android Google Maps Marker not updating immediately

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an app where a user is able to select a location. The map first centers around their GPS location, but the user is also able to drag the marker or type in a search bar. These all work, but I am finding a weird issue where the marker is not updating immediately.

It is updating, it's just one step behind...

Heres my code for onMarkerDragEnd:

```
    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
        //mLocMarker = marker; // this has no effect
        mLocMarker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker());
        mLocMarker.showInfoWindow();

        LatLng mPos = mLocMarker.getPosition();

        LatLng[] coordinates = new LatLng[kmlCoordinates.size()];
        coordinates = kmlCoordinates.toArray(coordinates);
        if (BorderPatrol.PointIsInRegion(mPos, coordinates)) {
            try {
                mAddress = getNearestStreetAddress(mPos);
                markerTitle = mAddress.getAddressLine(0);
                Log.d(TAG, "DRAG: Valid Address is " + mAddress.getAddressLine(0));
                isValidAddress = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            markerTitle   = "Out of Delivery Zone";
            markerSnippet = "Hold and drag to change location";
            Log.d(TAG, "Out of Delivery Zone: " + mPos);
            isValidAddress = false;
        }
        mLocMarker.setTitle(markerTitle);
        mLocMarker.setSnippet(markerSnippet);

        float mZoom = map.getCameraPosition().zoom;
        CameraUpdate mLoc = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder().target(mPos).zoom(mZoom).build());
        map.moveCamera(mLoc);
    }
```

So, mLocMarker is my single global Marker variable I am trying to update here.

The log within the border patrol method fires everytime - it returns an address and logs it. However, the Title and Snippet are not updating - or, they are, just always one event behind.

I'm totally stumped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it...

I wasn't calling  `mLocMarker.showInfoWindow()` everytime - I didn't think I had to, as this is a global variable and I call it on setup, but that was the issue!